# Android Studio icon not showing in taskbar - Windows 11

Tags: android-studio, taskbar, ico, windows-11

Recently I upgraded from Windows 10 to Windows 11. But now when I open Android Studio only a blank file icon appears on the taskbar.

[image]

Is there any way to retrieve the original Android Studio icon?

I have also checked that the `.ico` file exists in `C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\bin\studio.ico`

Comment: is it permanent when restarting the PC? Or just sometimes randomly? My android studio icon is showing fine on win11

Comment: @TorgeRosendahl Yes, it is permanent and always shows like that.

Answer (score 1):

You can click on Start and search for Android Studio ,then on the right side you will get an option of pin to taskbar, click on it. Now Android Studio icon will appear in Taskbar.
[image]
But why this happened?
This usually happens when the location of file has changed or it has been deleted! But why this happens during updating to Windows 11 in some PCs, only Microsoft knows!

Answer (score 1):

I did this and it showed for me:

- From start menu: right-click its icon.
- Click More -> Open file location.
- Right-lick the shortcut and choose Open file location.
- From the opened directory, open the file studio.ico with any app.
- And suddenly the taskbar refreshed and it showed.

Answer (score 0):

This is what's working for me:

1. From start menu: right-click the icon.
2. Click More -> Open file location.
3. Right-lick the shortcut and open Properties.
4. Change Icon -> OK -> Close.
5. Do step 3 & 4 again, because the first time didn't change the icon (in my case).

[image: Screenshot]